During building a flutter app, i keep gettting this error with namespace
This error keeps occurring whenever i run my app on an android emulator or tries to build it with flutter build appbundle
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':motion_sensors'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.


Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. Also please clarify if this only happens on the emulator.

Might be a duplicate of this

Seems this has to do with some affected plugins.
In my case the motion_sensor and google_api_headers
Motion Sensor
Goto your /Users/account_name/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/ and open the
Check the /android/main/Androidmanifest.xml package, that is
<manifest package='...'> and copy that package name into your android/build.gradle
In my case, my android now looks like this
android {
     namespace 'com.app.motion_sensors'
    compileSdkVersion 28
....

Do the same to any other package that it complains of have no namespace.
Now
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build appbundle

I hope this helps someone
